# jQuery show/hide different sets of form elements on same hyperlink

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a form which can have up to 6 children added to it.  Therefore there will be 6 sets of the following HTML:

```
            <table class="portletTable child" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" summary="Please enter some more details regarding your dependants">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <label for="indTitle">Title</label>
                </th>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <select id="indTitle" class="inlineSpace">
                        <option value="Please select">Please select...</option>
                        <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                        <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                        <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
                        <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                        <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
                        <option value="Other">Other</option>
                    </select>
                    <label for="indOther" class="inlineSpace">Other</label>
                    <input type="text" class="text" name="indOther" id="indOther" maxlength="20" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <label for="firstname">First name</label>
                </th>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <input type="text" class="text" maxlength="50" value="" id="firstname" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <label for="lastname">Last name</label>
                </th>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <input type="text" class="text" maxlength="50" value="" id="lastname" />
                </td>
            </tr>       
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <label for="dobDay">Date of birth</label>
                </th>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <select name="dobDay" id="dobDay" class="inlineSpace">
                        <option value="day">Day</option>
                    </select>
                    <label for="dobMonth" class="offScreen">Month</label>
                    <select name="dobMonth" id="dobMonth" class="inlineSpace">
                        <option value="month">Month</option>
                    </select>
                    <label for="dobYear" class="offScreen">Month</label>                
                    <select name="dobYear" id="dobYear">
                        <option value="year">Year</option>
                    </select>
                    <p class="fieldNote">You must be over 'minimum partner age' and under 'max partner age'</p>             
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Gender
                </th>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <input id="male" name="childGender" class="radio" type="radio" />
                    <label for="male" class="inlineSpace">Male</label>
                    <input id="female" name="childGender" class="radio" type="radio" />
                    <label for="female">Female</label>
                </td>
            </tr>               
        </table>
```

I need the first child to show by default and the following five to be hidden from view.

When a user clicks the following link i want the second child to show, if they click it again then the third child inputs show and so on...

```
<tr>
                <th class="dependant">
                    <a href="" class="add">Add another child to your policy</a>
                </th>
            </tr>
```

Obviously when the sixth child is shown the link should not display.

I also need the reverse to be true in that a user has the option to remove the latest added child with this hyperlink:

```
<tr>
                <th class="dependant">
                    <a href="" class="remove">Remove this child from your policy</a>
                </th>
            </tr>
```

If Javascript is turned off then all will show by default.

Thanks in advance if any of you can help.

Comment: I don't like these kind of questions. They just seem like the poster just wants someone to do his work for him. Why not look at the JQuery tutorials, download and print up a JQuery cheat-sheet, and then ask a question about a particular issue if you get stuck?

Comment: LoL!... sounds like homework? and you want it easy?... :)

Comment: Hi @ Josh.

Apologies i agree that i am being a little lazy.  Sorry will investigate further and raise any issues later when i inevitably get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$(function() {
    // Hide everything except the first one
    $('.portletTable').not(':first').hide();

    // Remove functionality
    $('.dependant .remove').click(function() {
        // Hide this child and move it to the end of the table
        $(this)
            .closest('.portletTable')
            .hide()
            .appendTo($(this).closest('form'));
    });

    // Show functionality
    $('.dependant .remove').click(function() {
        // Show the first hidden table
        $(this).closest('form').find('.portletTable:hidden:first').show();
    });
});
```

That should give you the functionality you want. You probably want to improve the remove functionality by resetting all inputs and selects to their default state.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.add').live('click',
   function() {
       //seek next element with class "child"
       var $nextChild = $(this).parents('.child').next('.child :first');  
       if ($nextChild.size() > 0)  //exists?
           $nextChild.show();  //show it
   }
);

$('.remove').live('click',
   function() {
       //hide the parent with class "child"
       $(this).parents('.child').hide();
   }
);
```

Replace `live` with `bind` if you don't plan to add links later.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all tables with separated IDs, and manipulate their visibility state with document.getElementById("table_id").style.display = "none" or document.getElementById("table_id").style.display = "block".